# Inheritance and extending classes

Tags: java, android, inheritance, extensibility

This will probably have an obvious answer to many but I can't seem to figure it out. I am trying to make an api call within an android application, but keep running into "..... cannot be resolved" I have three Java classes, FoodSearchActivity, GetItemsActivity and GetData!

```
FoodSearchActivity extends Activity;
```

This class declares the following

```
public ListView list;
public Button btnSearch;
public EditText txtFoodSearch;
```

but in the `GetItemsActivity` class, `txtFoodSearch` cannot be resolved unless I extend `FoodSearchActivity`.  Which in turn means I can't implement `AsyncTask`. When `GetItemsActivity` does implement `AsyncTask` I get the error:

```
 " The type AsyncTask<String,String,String> cannot be a superinterface of GetItemsActivity; a superinterface must be an interface"

GetItemsActivity extends FoodSearchActivity;
```

To try solve this I created a new class `GetData` which extends `AsyncTask<String, String, String>`

```
GetData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
```

I have no errors when i do this but when I do

```
txtFoodSearch.getText().toString();
```

I am back at the `txtFoodSearch` cannot be resolved. `txtFoodSearch` is an `EditText` field which takes user input. How can i change this so `txtFoodSearch` is visible in the other classes??
It's already declared as public. Any tips or advice would be great. Can post source code if needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following the public declaration that you have assigned to **txtFoodSearch** with the declaration of **static**. This is because the **static** keyword makes variables such as **txtFoodSearch** globally accessible, while their class is loaded.

So, after you declare **public static txtFoodSearch** in its corresponding class, you should be able to just do: **Classname.txtFoodSearch** in any other class to access the content of **txtFoodSearch**. Be certain however that the class containing **txtFoodSearch** is declared as **public**.